# Using a C++/CLI/CX/etc data package from an UWP C# app

Tags: c#, uwp, c++-cli, c++-cx

After days of experimenting that only led to partial success, I'd like to ask whether I have any chance or I'll invariably end up in a dead end. I have an UWP C# App, the usual framework, planned to be distributed in the Windows Store. And I also have a data package written in C++ (mostly C) that I used earlier. The old, non-managed code doesn't call any Windows API at all, it's just a data format package. But I need to access it directly from the C# side, and its most important type is authored as a value struct, with many overloaded operators (and this is good so, that approach is just perfect for the application domain).

From a WPF application, I wouldn't have any problem at all, a C++/CLI wrapper of a `value struct`, exposing everything. But the UWP app doesn't want to do the same. If I use the same C++/CLI wrapper, although I can get it to compile by itself, the UWP project will flat out refuse to reference the C++/CLI project.

I also tried the newer C++/CX flavor but that comes with many limitations, no specialized constructors, no overloading. It seems to be sandboxed much more than I'd need.

Is there any solution I missed? Maybe still using the C++/CLI (which has the benefit of being already written :-) ) somehow from under an UWP application?

Comment: You cannot use C++/CLI in a UWP app, it has unusual AppDomain-related hosting requirements that .NETCore cannot provide.  That's been changing as of late, as part of .NETCore v3 they created a new host called ijwhost that can support C++/CLI.  It is in preview right now and whether it can work in a UWP app is a fair stretch.  You need C++/CX if you want to avoid the arrows in your back.

Comment: Oh, well. I don't yet know if I can compile it with /CX, I started to experiment but plenty of error messages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I succeeded. There is an intermediate helper class (not a struct because of the inherent limitations) written in C++/CX, and the actual struct I use is defined in C#, using this intermediate.

The error messages in the process were mostly related to the underlying code being very old, C, not even C++, with all the linking and externing stuff involved. But no matter how old it is, it still works...

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 1803 you should have access to a complete C++ implementation

> [C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/) is an entirely standard modern C++17 language projection
>   for Windows Runtime

If you want to consume C++ code from C#, then you probably want to compile it as a Windows Runtime Component, as those can be consumed in any other UWP-supported language. 
I think [this is demonstrated in this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/author-events), even through the app consuming it seems to be in C++